# why the element in my List<Integer> is type Character?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, integer, character

[image]

As shown in above picture, my method accepts `List includedDays, and I expect the element is of type `Integer, but why in debug mode, I find that the element is of type`Character?

`includeDays` comes from the following code:

```
List<Integer> includedDays = getDowByTrmClassId(trmClassId);
```

and `getDowByTrmClassId(trmClassId)` is defined as:

```
List<Integer> getDowByTrmClassId(Integer trmClassId){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    String sql = " select DOW from TRM_CLASS_DOW cdow " + 
            "where (cdow.UPDATE_MODE is null or cdow.UPDATE_MODE <> 'D') " + 
            " AND cdow.TRM_CLASS_ID = :trmClassId  " + 
            " ORDER BY cdow.dow";
    Query sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    sqlQuery.setParameter("trmClassId", trmClassId);        
    List<Integer> classDows = sqlQuery.list();
    return classDows;       
}
```

the column `dow` is of type `varchar(1)`

Comment: Kindly add additional code on how you initialized those parameters? (Following question is optional) How you uses those variables? That may help debugging easier. Those code is technically correct, but the debugger doesn't agree. Therefore, I might be because of the process of initialization or processing. Otherwise, your JVM has some issue.

Comment: the List<Integer> includeDays initialization code is added

Comment: *"I expect the element is of type `Integer`"* Why would you expect that, when the column is type `varchar(1)`, and you haven't defined any explicit mapping in Hibernate? With nothing else to go on but the `varchar(1)` column type, I would have expected `String`, certainly not `Integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the culprit on your problem.

```
the column dow is of type varchar(1)
```

Varchar should return a String result for this field. But I found that hibernate has some issue on this, when varchar contain single character, the result will be converted to char/Character datatype in your Java. Look at these issues, [HHH-2220](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2220?focusedCommentId=27183&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel), [HHH-2304](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBPAPP-7291)  and other with the same problem. It pointed out [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2220?focusedCommentId=27183&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel), and I quote

> Currently Hibernate supports a kind of "automagic" mapping from SQL types to Hibernate/Java types - because of the many ambiguities in doing such mapping it will sometime not match what you actually want.

**Suggestion:**
Since you really expect a Character because of the above code and the issue, you should fix the datatype issue on your database and Java. You can permanently convert you database to correct datatype (Integer if it really range from 0-9). Or if you can't do database modification, you can do it by creating helper class/method to manually parse each result to Integer like using a method something like:

```
/**
* You parser method of Character to Integer
*/
public List<Integer> converToIngeter(List resultList){//This should accept your resultSet from your query as List
    List<Integer> toReturn  = new ArrayList<>();

    resultList.stream().forEach((o)->{
        if(Character.isDigit((Character) o)){//(Character) o) is just an insurance that the instance is Character
            toReturn.add(Character.getNumericValue((Character)o));
        }
    });


     /* Or you do some other parsing 
      */
     return toReturn;
}
```

In your code

```
List<Integer> getDowByTrmClassId(Integer trmClassId){
    . . . //Your other code here
    sqlQuery.setParameter("trmClassId", trmClassId);
    List<Integer> classDows = converToIngeter(sqlQuery.list()); //converToIngeter(list) was added to convert the result to Integer
    return classDows;       
}
```

You can look other char to integer parsing like [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-char-to-int) on the internet.

Or To fix datatype problem of Varchar being returned as Character on Java, [This](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2220?focusedCommentId=27419&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-27419) answer suggested to add `.addScalar("PREFIX", Hibernate.STRING);` on your query. Eg.

```
sqlQuery.setParameter("trmClassId", trmClassId);
sqlQuery.addScalar("PREFIX", Hibernate.STRING);
```

Then, parse them to Integer later on.

===============

**UPDATE**:

Remove unrelated answer. Thanks you Andreas for pointing out some that I have neglected.

Comment: *"declared your Java object's corresponding field for that database column is an integer"* Where did that happen? I see no such declaration in the question code. --- If you're referring to the `List<Integer> classDows = sqlQuery.list()` statement, remember that type-erasure means that the `list()` method doesn't know anything about the `Integer` generic type argument. All it sees is that it should return a `List`, so essentially a `List<? extends Object>`.

Comment: It may came form the EntityBean of that JPQL. As of what I know, you cannot use JPQL without using non-entity. As also pointed out by the selected answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873902/select-non-entities-with-jpa. The question doesn't not provided the entity so I assume the datatype in the entity.

Comment: What EntityBean? What JPQL? There is no EntityBean in the question, and there is only SQL, no JPQL, in the question.

Comment: I found the JPQL here `select DOW from TRM_CLASS_DOW cdow`. This should not be a native query for an SQL-based query. Most of sql-based query uses `select DOW.* from TRM_CLASS_DOW AS cdow `.

Comment: For the question of What is entityBean. it is the Java Persistence API (JPA). Please see it here: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/EJB3_Services-Entity_Beans.html

Comment: I didn't ask "what" an EntityBean *is*. To clarify, I was asking you *which* EntityBean you seem to believe exists in the question. --- *"I found the JPQL here"* That is SQL, not JPQL, as proven by the fact that the string is used in call to `createSQLQuery()`, not `createQuery()`. That is the *fact* of the question code, so the start of this answer saying *"I notice that you are using JPQL"* is erroneous, and causes the rest of the answer to be **off point**.

Comment: yeah, perhaps I will just remove the first part of my answer.

Comment: Why would as sql table have a column of varchar(1) rather than char(1)?

Comment: For the reason of Varchar(1) instead of char for the table structure is something that I don't understand either. But it is reported there were some who have, so yeah, some do that. But something with the content and not the structure of database table alone. For example, accidentally or even intentionally inserted a single char to a Varchar(10) will result to the same problem based on that reported issue.